# Matching a real number key in a Python dictionary

Tags: python, floating-point, python-3.x

I have a dictionary that provides a mapping from real number tuples to an identifying integer.  Given a list of tuples containing numbers that are within a tolerance of, but not *exactly* equal to those in the dictionary, I would like to produce a list of the corresponding integers.

Example:

```
tdict = {(0.334, 0.333, 0.333):1, (0.167, 0.666, 0.167):2, (0.5, 0.5, 0):3}
tlist = [(0.333, 0.333, 0.333), (0.16667, 0.6666667, 0.17), (0.34, 0.33, 0.33), (0.5001, 0.4999, 0.0)]
tol = 0.01
```

Running the code I want should produce the result

```
ilist = [1,2,1,3]
```

since all numbers in each of the tuples are within the given tolerance of those in the corresponding tuples in `tdict`.  I could do this by iterating over `tdict.keys()` and comparing to each one individually, but I feel like there should be a better way.  What is the most efficient way to get the corresponding integers to these tuples?  It doesn't have to involve a dictionary, that just seemed most natural to me.  I'm using Python 3.

Comment: Dictionaries are only good for exact matches, which are nearly impossible for floating point numbers even at the best of times. I'd start with a list instead.

Comment: You could compute the square of the distance of each point in the list to each point in the dictionary keys and check if it's below the tolerance squared. That would speed up the search by eliminating a lot of square-root calculations.

Comment: Another speed-up might be to classify the dictionary points somehow, say by what quadrant of space they lie in, and then only compare the list point being searched for to points in its region of space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You obviously want to project points in 3D-space on a 3D grid with a certain grid spacing (which is directly related to your tolerance value) and create some kind of histogram. Write yourself a projection function: It takes an arbitrary 3-element list/tuple (a vector describing a point in space) as argument and projects it onto a certain grid point. You do this for filling up your dictionary as well as for reading it out. Furthermore, regarding the keys in your dictionary, I think you should go with tuples of integers instead of floats, because I am not sure if floats can ever be identical.

This is an implementation example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from random import random as rn

class Grid(object):
    def __init__(self, spacing):
        self.spacing = spacing
        self.griddict = defaultdict(int)

    def add_point(self, coords):
        """
        `vid`, a voxel id, is a tuple of indices, indicating one grid
        bin for each dimension, e.g. (1, 5, 2)
        rule: i_x = int(floor(x_coord / spacing))
        """
        vid = tuple([int(c//self.spacing) for c in coords])
        self.griddict[vid] += 1

    def get_point(self, coords):
        vid = tuple([int(c//self.spacing) for c in coords])
        return self.griddict[vid]

    def vid_centercoords(self, vid):
        """
        Return the real coordinates in space for a certain voxel,
        which is identified by its voxel id `vid` (a tuple of indices).
        """
        return tuple([(i-1)*self.spacing + self.spacing/2 for i in vid])



N = 20
fillpoints = [(rn(),rn(),rn()) for _ in xrange(N)]
testpoints = [(rn(),rn(),rn()) for _ in xrange(N)]

grid = Grid(spacing=0.3)

for p in fillpoints:
    grid.add_point(p)

print [grid.get_point(p) for p in testpoints]
```

What it does: it creates 20 random vectors in 3D space (all coordinates between 0 and 1). It populates a 3D grid using these points in space. The grid has a spacing of 0.3 in each dimension. Each of these 20 points in space is assigned to a certain voxel (just a word for a 3D pixel) in the grid. Each assignment increased the counter of the corresponding voxel by 1 (rendering the grid to be a histogram). Then, another random set of 20 vectors is used to read out the voxels. These points are again projected onto voxels, but this time the counter is just returned instead of increased. Execution test:

```
$ python gridtest.py 
[2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Execution with your data:

```
fillpoints = [(0.334, 0.333, 0.333), (0.167, 0.666, 0.167), (0.167, 0.666, 0.167), (0.5, 0.5, 0), (0.5, 0.5, 0), (0.5, 0.5, 0)]
testpoints = [(0.333, 0.333, 0.333), (0.16667, 0.6666667, 0.17), (0.34, 0.33, 0.33), (0.5001, 0.4999, 0.0)]

grid = Grid(spacing=0.03)
for p in fillpoints:
    grid.add_point(p)
print [grid.get_point(p) for p in testpoints]
```

It prints `[1, 2, 1, 3]` as desired. I haven't thought deeply about the relation `spacing=3*tolerance`. It likely is wrong. I only know that there is a deterministic relation. Proving/finding this formula is left for you as an exercise :)

Comment: I am writing this code to process some floating-point data.  Unfortunately I do not have enough control over the data to demand that it be integer.

Comment: @astay13, this approach transforms the float tuples to integer tuples only in the internal grid representation. I have updated the code. It is now a working example. The methods of this grid class can deal with float tuples perfectly fine. The `fillpoints` and `testpoints` actually are lists of 3-tuples of floats. `testpoints` corresponds to `tlist` in your example.

Comment: That makes sense now.  That's a very interesting solution.

Answer (score 2):

1. Sort `tdict.keys()` by distance to each point of `tlist` in turn.
2. Pick the first few and look them up in `tdict`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to numpy, you can use [numpy.allclose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) to check for a match:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.allclose((0.334, 0.333, 0.333), (0.333, 0.333, 0.333))
False
>>> numpy.allclose((0.334, 0.333, 0.333), (0.333, 0.333, 0.333), atol=0.1)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a look up function (which looks for a rounded version of the tuple):

```
def look_up_tdict( t ):
    return tdict[ (float('%.3f' % t[0]),
                   float('%.3f' % t[1]),
                   float('%.3f' % t[2])
                 ]
```

*Note: this will give an error if nothing in the dictionary is close to `t`.* Then you can populate `ilist`:

```
ilist = [ look_up_tdict(t) for t in tlist ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 tolerance = 0.1
 for i in tlist:
      list2 = filter(lambda x:abs(sum(i)-sum(x))<tolerance,tdict
      print [tdict[itm] for itm in list2]
```

I think that will work ... not positive though ... in fact it looks like it doesnt quite give you your desired output